# Arifactory pypi: get latest version of an egg file

Tags: artifactory, pypi, egg

We have an artifactory pypi repository on which I push a (versioned) egg file, that I can retrieve with a link of this type

```
https://artifactoryrepo.com/pipy/myartifact-0.3.egg
```

however I would like to be able to get the `latest` available version (with a maven jar I woud do `com.mygroup:myartifact:latest`). Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: As far as I remember `pip` doesn't install egg files, it only works with source distributions and wheels. How do you install eggs? `easy_install`?

Comment: in my case, I use them for `pyspark`, so I would use the command `--py-files` to add them to the python path at runtime